# Right justify a component within a div in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Suppose:

`props.data1 = 'data1'` and `props.data2 = 'data2'`

In React, I have the following code:

```
      <div>
        {props.data1}&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;{props.data2}
      </div>
```

Which appears like: `data1        data2`.

What I am trying to do is *right justify* only data2 so it looks like the following:

`data1                                data2`

Assuming that is the furthest data2 can be pushed horizontally. Is there any tag/CSS that I can add to enable this? I've tried using span, but it causes `data2` to be pushed to a newline in React.

Comment: Really don't understand the result example you're giving how do you want the result displayed exactly do you want them both each one on a line and both aligned to right??

Comment: I want them both displayed on a single line, with `data1` aligned to the left and `data2` aligned to the right.

Comment: I see writing solution can be done with css and html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to achieve this you'll need two child elements on the HTML side like so:

```html
<div class="container">
<span>data1</span>
<span>data2</span>
</div>
```

css:

```css
.container {
display:flex;
flex-direction: row;
justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind adding the contained text in their own elements you can use [`display: flex;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) on the containing `div`, and set its `justify-content` attribute to `space-between`.

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid salmon;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span>data1</span>
  <span>data2</span>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are triyng to separate the texts, you can use **css flex**.

```
<div style="width: 100%; display: flex; justify-content: space-between">
  <span>{data1}</span>
  <span>{data2}</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <p>data1</p>
  <p>data2</p>
</div>
```